# Save webpage with linked images (full size)

Tags: windows, firefox, webpage

I have tried some browsers and addons for saving webpages. Opera saves them in MHTML, just like Firefox does with an add-on. That won't download / save the big images so they won't work. MHTML neither.

Now I have installed MAF (Mozilla Archive Format), but that does the same.

Any ideas how could I save a webpage/article 1:1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically need some form of spidering software- In addition to the classic wget, the one that most people recommend is [httrack](http://www.httrack.com/) - it has a nice GUI, and is fairly simple. If its for a single page, just set link depth to a low number.